# Why strip() does not clear all whitespaces in python?

Tags: python, string

I have this code:

```
with open("db.csv", "r") as file:
    for row in file:
        row = row.strip()
        print("Stripped:", row)
        task = tuple(row.split(";"))
        print("Splitted:", task)
```

Thats opens this csv file:

```
asdf; [(datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 23, 14, 8, 8, 198986), 'asdf')]; 2012-12-12 12:12:00; 0
adsf; [(datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 23, 14, 45, 30, 806811), 'asdf')]; None; 0
```

The output is this:

```
Stripped: asdf; [(datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 23, 14, 8, 8, 198986), 'asdf')]; 2012-12-12 12:12:00; 0
Splitted: ('asdf', " [(datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 23, 14, 8, 8, 198986), 'asdf')]", ' 2012-12-12 12:12:00', ' 0')
Stripped: adsf; [(datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 23, 14, 45, 30, 806811), 'asdf')]; None; 0
Splitted: ('adsf', " [(datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 23, 14, 45, 30, 806811), 'asdf')]", ' None', ' 0')
```

Why `row.strip()` only removes `"\n"` line, but not the spaces in the begining of the item on the splitted list?

EDIT:
I added `row = row.replace(" ", "")` before splitting, which works as workaround, but I would still like to know why `strip()` did not work as I expected.

Comment: Try experimenting with lstrip() and rstrip().

Comment: You stripped *before* you split.

Comment: For reading a CSV, use a [CSV Reader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html). CSV is not as simple as splitting at `;` There can be `;` as part of the data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason is: because it is defined like that:

> Return a copy of the string with the **leading and trailing** characters removed.

Source: [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip), emphasis mine.

How should `strip()` know that you will split it afterwards and don't want spaces after that? Therefore, you need to `split()` first and then call `strip()` on all items.

In contrast to your workaround:

> Return a copy of the string with **all occurrences** of substring old replaced by new.

Source: [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace), emphasis mine .

A note of warning: your current CSV data might be so simple that you can just split it at the semicolons. However, it is possible to have the semicolon as part of the data, like

```
data1;"data;2";data3
```

Make it yourself a habit to use the right tool for the job. In this case a [CSV reader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader). It will handle the special cases for you.

Answer (score 2):

In your function, you called the `strip()` on the full string, thus if you string was:

" a b c "

This will turn into

"a b c"

All spaces removed are only on the edges.

Thus, to remove all spaces you'd have to split *before* using strip, with a for loop or list comprehension such as:

```
task = tuple([item.strip() for item in row.split(";")])
```